# Face Recognition Login - C# with OpenCV

Tags: c#, opencv, face-recognition

There is something obvious that I'm not seeing in this code, but every image return 100% similarity. Anyone can point me what I'm doing wrong?

I'm new using OpenCV and I will have a uploaded photo and I will need to compare with another one taken from a website in real time login.

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult ReconhecerImagem([FromBody] ImagemDTO imagemDTO)
        {
            // Converter a imagem base64 em bytes
            string base64String = imagemDTO.ImagemBase64.Replace(" ", "+");
            byte[] imageData = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);

            // Carregar a imagem usando OpenCV
            Mat imagem = Cv2.ImDecode(imageData, ImreadModes.Color);

            // Realizar o reconhecimento facial com o OpenCV
            // Aqui você precisa implementar a lógica de reconhecimento facial com OpenCV,
            // como carregar imagens de referência, extrair características faciais etc.
            // Supondo que você tenha uma imagem de referência previamente cadastrada, chamada "imagemReferencia":

            // Carregar a imagem de referência usando OpenCV
            Mat imagemReferencia = Cv2.ImRead("C:\\Users\\wrwon\\Downloads\\Foto.jpg", ImreadModes.Color);

            // Redimensionar as imagens para terem o mesmo tamanho
            Size imageSize = new Size(150, 150);
            Cv2.Resize(imagem, imagem, imageSize);
            Cv2.Resize(imagemReferencia, imagemReferencia, imageSize);

            // Converter as imagens para escala de cinza
            Mat grayImagem = new Mat();
            Cv2.CvtColor(imagem, grayImagem, ColorConversionCodes.BGR2GRAY);
            Mat grayImagemReferencia = new Mat();
            Cv2.CvtColor(imagemReferencia, grayImagemReferencia, ColorConversionCodes.BGR2GRAY);

            // Criar um objeto EigenFaceRecognizer
            var recognizer = EigenFaceRecognizer.Create();

            // Treinar o modelo com a imagem de referência
            recognizer.Train(new[] { grayImagemReferencia }, new[] { 1 });

            // Realizar o reconhecimento facial na imagem capturada
            var result = recognizer.Predict(grayImagem);

            // Normalizar a distância em uma escala de 0 a 100
            double normalizedDistance = (result - 0) / (10000 - 0) * 100;

            // Calcular a similaridade como 100 - distância normalizada
            double similarity = 100 - normalizedDistance;

            // Verificar se a similaridade é maior ou igual a 95%
            if (similarity >= 95)
            {
                // Reconhecimento facial bem-sucedido
                return Ok(new { success = true });
            }
            else
            {
                // Reconhecimento facial falhou
                return Ok(new { success = false });
            }
        }
    }

    public class ImagemDTO
    {
        public string ImagemBase64 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you training the classifier every time you predict new labels? Are you training it with *only* one image? Also, check the return values of `recognizer.Predict` because you usually get two numbers: the predicted label and the prediction confidence.

Comment: the recognizer can't recognize "unknown". ANY input is classified as one of the training labels. the API docs show me something about a "confidence" value. if you're lucky, that's usable. probably not though. -- you need to run that face recognizer with a large dataset or a trained model (eigenfaces). then you need to classify some face according to the model, which gives you a feature vector. THEN you can compare faces for dissimilarity.

Comment: most people use opencvsharp over emgu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compute the **eigen vector** of the test face image and that of the target image and then use a **threshold** to check if the two faces are similar. There is a library called Emgu CV which is a C# wrapper you can use to compute the eigen vector of a test image. You will need a classifier for the face feature extraction including the eigen value and eigen vector.

If you desire to check for the similarity of images based on a single image then you don't need a trained model but if you want the Software to recognize face images then you need to train a model using a neural network and then use the model to recognize a sample test face with the corresponding  correct label that was used during the training process.
There is a library called **Emgutf**(Emgu Cv Tensor Flow ) which is a library that let's you build, train and test neural networks for the needs of image processing, face recognition included.